# How to use a dynamic ID for a query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In my code I insert a row in my MySQL table, if it does not exist. Since the query requires an unique index, I am just inserting `$id`, which is just a static value of `1` (line #8).

```
public function prepare($author, $arr) {
    $conn = new mysqli($this->servername, $this->username, $this->password, $this->db_name);

    foreach ($arr as $value) {

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT IGNORE INTO kh_comments(id, author,abstract) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");

        $id = 1; // Just a static value

        $stmt->bind_param("dss", $id, $author, $value['id']);
        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->close();
        $conn->close();
    }
}
```

I would now like to use a dynamic value instead of `1`. The variable `$id`should be smart enough to figure out which ID is affected. Or if there is another way to do this, I appreciate any suggestions!

[image]

Comment: Make `id` `auto-incremented primary key` in your `db table` and remove it from query and everything will be fine

Comment: from your table definition set id as auto increment column

Comment: @Anant `id` is already `auto-incremented` but when I remove it from my query, nothing can be inserted anymore.

Comment: @Reza if id is auto-incremented then try to use null in place of $id

Comment: @Anant if use `null` insetad of `$id`, I'll get an error but if I change the value of variable `$id` to `null`, the row can be inserted but also if it already exists in my table and that is not really what I want.

Comment: @Anant I have tried your code but it is still inserting new rows, even if they already exist. My ID is already AUTO_INCREMENT. You can see an image of it in my updated question.

Comment: primary key too my brother (id need to be)

Comment: Isn't it already a primary key when the key icon is disabled? I have also deleted my table and used the SQL code in the answer of Shadow in order to create a new table with `PRIMARY KEY (id)` but it looks still the same.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL you can define [auto increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html) fields using the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute in a `create table` or `alter table` command:

```
CREATE TABLE animals (
     id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

During the insertion you just do not assign any value to that column and MySQL will automatically assign its value for you:

```
INSERT INTO animals (name) VALUES
    ('dog'),('cat'),('penguin'),
    ('lax'),('whale'),('ostrich');
```

As the linked documentation says:

> You can retrieve the most recent automatically generated AUTO_INCREMENT value with the LAST_INSERT_ID() SQL function or the mysql_insert_id() C API function. These functions are connection-specific, so their return values are not affected by another connection which is also performing inserts.

In mysqli use [mysqli_insert_id() function](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) to retrieve this value.

Answer (score 0):

id has an AUTO_INCREMENT value. You don't have to put a value for it. I think this was your question.